# Classic ASP Response.redirect

Tags: asp-classic

I wish to redirect a user to another page after logon.

The code below:

```
Response.Redirect("../agent/info.asp")
```

works fine - for Safari, IE, and Chrome. Not Firefox.

The code below:

```
Response.Redirect("agent/info.asp")
```

works in Firefox, but nothing else.

Answer (score 4):

If the page you are redirecting to isn't in the same directory, you're generally better off using either the full URL or the full virtual path like so (assuming `/agent/` is in a directory below the root like what your example implies):

```
Response.Redirect("/agent/info.asp")
```

or

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.example.com/agent/info.asp")
```

More information and examples can be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Don't know why I just thought of this, but I have another site on the same server that redirects fine from all browsers... Must be a server site configuration setting...

Comment: @Sheldon using the same code? It's worth investigating, but *usually* anything of this nature would not be influenced by server settings, much less anything likely to have been changed on a per-site basis.